# Doing cs50 Finance and "buy" is generating a run time error

Tags: cs50, finance

My error is where I adjust cash to reflect the purchase of stock.  The command line error is:  RuntimeError: near "['user_id']": syntax error.  I have used both "  "  and '  ' correctly within the line of code.  Also further up in command line I got:  ERROR: Exception on /buy [POST], which I don't understand.  Please let me know if you have any thought.  Thanks.

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure ticker was submitted
        if not request.form.get("symbol"):
            return apology("must input stock symbol")


        # Get symbol and make sure it exists
        symbol = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

        if not symbol:
            return apology("symbol does not exist")


        # Ensure shares entered greater than zero
        number=int(request.form.get("shares"))
        if number <= 0:
            return apology("must enter number of shares to buy")

        # set up dict to store purchase info: name, price, symbol
        quote = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))


        # Dollars needed for purchase

        pcash=number * quote["price"]

        # Is there enough cash in account to purchase
        ecash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        if pcash >= ecash[0]["cash"]:
            return apology("Not enough cash to buy that amount of stock")

        # Record buy in trades.db for user-id
        x=datetime.datetime.now()
        db.execute("INSERT INTO trades (datetime, symbol, shares, price, total, id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", x, quote["symbol"], number, quote["price"], pcash, session["user_id"])


        # Adjust cash to reflect purchase
        y=ecash[0]["cash"]-pcash
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash=? WHERE id=session['user_id']", y)

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

     # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

Comment: Please include the full errors

Answer (score 0):

This `UPDATE users SET cash=? WHERE id=session['user_id']` is the query that sqlite is trying to execute. sqlite doesn't know from `session['user_id']` (it's a python variable). The method will accept multiple placeholders (ie `?`). Use a placeholder for the WHERE clause, and send the value as an additional argument.

Comment: Correct!  Thank you.